# Select only entities with n relations from an n:m relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, relational-division

I have an m:n relationship of images and tags in my database, which uses a crosstable to model this.
Table `imgs` contains much more information than just `img_id`, but that is all that's required to uniquely identify an image.

I want to find every `img_id` which has both tagA and tagB (and tagC and so on, I'll build this string so it won't really matter whether its two or ten tags).

[image]

Now, where I'm stuck is, of course first you'll join `imgs` with `img_tags` with `tags`, add a where clause for the tags;

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM imgs 
INNER JOIN img_tags ON imgs.img_id = img_tags.img_id 
INNER JOIN tags     ON img_tags.tag_id = tags.tag_id
WHERE tag = 'tagA' OR tag = 'tagB';
```

and then you'll get rows with identical `imgs` information, only differing in `tag` and `tag_id`. Now I should be able to count those, targeting only those which appear in the same amount as tags were supplied (`Count(*) = n`), and then using `group by` to aggregate them? But I can't quite figure it out.
In case it might be of relevance, you might assume the fields in img_tags are both foreign keys referencing the other tables, however that is not the case, they are not linked in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation like this:

```
SELECT i.* 
FROM imgs i JOIN
     img_tags it
     ON i.img_id = it.img_id JOIN
     tags t
     ON it.tag_id = t.tag_id
WHERE tag IN ('tagA', 'tagB')
GROUP BY i.img_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Aggregating by `i.img_id` is safe -- and supported by the SQL standard -- assuming that `img_id` is the primary key in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Here is on approach using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM imgs i
WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM img_tags it
    INNER JOIN tags t ON it.tag_id = t.tag_id
    WHERE i.img_id = it.img_id AND t.tag IN('tagA', 'tagB')
) = 2
```

This assumes no duplicate tags in your data structure. Otherwise, you can use `COUNT(DISTINCT t.tag)` instead of `COUNT(*)`.

You can also use aggregation:

```
SELECT i.id
FROM imgs i
INNER JOIN img_tags it ON i.img_id = it.img_id 
INNER JOIN tags t      ON it.tag_id = t.tag_id
WHERE t.tag IN('tagA', 'tagB')
GROUP BY i.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: For anyone stopping by, using aggregation is much faster ( about 5 times for me).

Answer (score 1):

If there are not many tags involved, I would just use exists (or not exists if you want to exclude some tags) for this

```
select *
from imgs
where
    exists(select 1 from img_tags it where it.tag_id=(select tag_id from tags where tag='tagA') and it.img_id=imgs.img_id)
    and exists(select 1 from img_tags it where it.tag_id=(select tag_id from tags where tag='tagB') and it.img_id=imgs.img_id);
```

especially if you end up wanting to do more complicated boolean expressions e.g. (A and (B or not C)).